# Gradle, OSGI and dependency management

Tags: gradle, osgi

I'm new to Gradle, please, help me to understand the following. I'm trying to build an OSGI web app via Intellij Idea + Gradle. I've found that Gradle has OSGI plugin, which is described here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/osgi_plugin.html

But I have no idea on how to add dependency on, for example, org.apache.felix.dependencymanager which is OSGI bundle. So, I need this jar while compilation, and I don't need it in my resulting jar. I think, that I need something similar to maven 'provided' scope, or something like that.

P.S. Does anyone understand, what 'TBD' means in Gradle documentation? Does this means it has to be implemented in future, or is some mechanism is implemented, but is not yet described in docs?

Comment: Don't use the Gradle OSGi plugin, instead use [this](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md#gradle-plugin-for-workspace-builds).

Comment: If using a standard gradle build, the non-workspace model is probably the desired choice: https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle/README.md#gradle-plugin-for-non-workspace-builds

Comment: @NeilBartlett : Thanks for your advice and sorry for my late answer - could you, please, give an example of using this plugin for non-workspace build or correct my build script? My very simple project is here, the bundle is assumed just to export package [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0CaRXyG1f1OSk1STjMwSDh2UTA), but I receive the following message during gradle 'jar' task: Warning: Classpath is empty. Private-Package and Export-Package can only expand from the classpath when there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the plugin I wrote, [osgi-run](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/osgi-run), which was designed to make it extremely easy to play with OSGi without using any external tools like Eclipse (though osgi-run can generate a Manifest file for you, which you can point at from your IDE to get IDE OSGi support - this is what I do using IntelliJ), just Gradle.

With `osgi-run`, you just add a dependency to whatever you want as with any Java project... whether it should be provided by the environment or not does not matter at compile time, this is a deployment-time concern.

For example, add to your build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'osgi' // or other OSGi plugin if you prefer

repositories {
    mavenCentral() // add repos to get your dependencies from
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.dependencymanager:4.3.0"
}
```

**Note:** the `osgi` plugin is just required to turn your jar into a bundle. `osgi-run` does not do that.

If you have any runtime dependencies that should be present in the OSGi environment but not in the compile classpath, do something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    osgiRuntime 'org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.8'
}
```

Now write some code, and once you're ready to run a OSGi container with your stuff in it, add these lines to the build.gradle file:

```
// this should be the first line
plugins {
    id "com.athaydes.osgi-run" version "1.4.3"
}

...

// deployment to OSGi container config
runOsgi {
    // which bundles do you want to add?
    // transitive deps will be automatically added
    bundles += project

    // do not deploy jars matching these regexes (not needed, this is the default)
    excludedBundles = ['org\\.osgi\\..*']

    // make the manifest visible to the IDE for OSGi support
    copyManifestTo file( 'auto-generated/MANIFEST.MF' )
}
```

Run:

```
gradle createOsgiRuntime
```

And find your full OSGi environment, ready to run, in the `build/osgi` directory.

Run it with:

```
build/osgi/run.sh # or run.bat in Windows
```

You can even run it during the build already:

```
gradle runOsgi
```

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly try it, as soon as I deal with building bundles.

Comment: Is the osgi-run avialable with Gradle 6 ?

Comment: I haven't updated osgi-run in a while! If you have trouble pls create an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

So you probably want to make your own `provided` configuration.

```
configurations {
    // define new scope
    provided
}
sourceSets {
    // add the configurations to the compile classpath but not runtime
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    // be sure to add the provided configs to your tests too if needed
    test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided
}
dependencies {
    // declare your provided dependencies
    provided 'org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.dependencymanager:4.3.0'
}
```

Also the suggestion above about using the `bndtool` directly instead of the gradle provided `osgi` plugin is a good one.  The gradle plugin has many deficiencies and is really just a wrapper to the `bndtool` anyways.  Also the gradle team has declared they do not have the bandwidth or expertise to fix the `osgi` plugin [1].

[1] https://discuss.gradle.org/t/the-osgi-plugin-has-several-flaws/2546/5

Comment: If you need the jar for compilation only, I would use the new `compileOnly` configuration added in Gradle 2.12 instead of hacking it in like above.